# Admin has no rights, not even to own desktop

Tags: centos, permissions

For some reason my admin account lost access to everything. I can't see any files on my desktop; When I try to open a file I get the error

> Nautilus could not create the following required folders: /home/admin/Desktop, /home/admin/.nautilus

I can't even run Firefox.

I did a desperate move by adding the 'admin' user to the 'root' group, the result is still the same however. I have not restarted the server however, should I do that? I am on CentOs.

Thanks

Comment: After adding admin to the root group, you'll need to log out and log back in again.

Comment: You would definitely like to know what happened just before you lost access. I've seen terrible examples (and unfortunately been the one to recover others' mistakes)  including typos on `sudo`, like recursive `chown` and `chmod` on `/*` instead of the correct directory. Is this just on this account or server wide?

Comment: I did a whole system restart, but nothing has changed. I can't even open simple things like the 'account informarion' window... luckily I still have access to the console. Unfortunately I have no idea what happened as this is the works of my past sys admins.

Comment: What's also interesting is that when I click on Administrator > Quit, it does nothing. I have to click on "switch user", and from there on I can restart/shutdown etc. But the admin account seems totally broken.

Comment: Is your name "admin"? If not, you really should use a different login name.

Comment: @MichaelHampton why?

Comment: Because "admin" is a role, and you are a person. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged in to another account, and found out that the whole 'admin' directory belonged to group 'nginx'. I simply added 'admin' to that group, and the world is nice again!

Comment: Did you (or someone) perhaps run `chown`, `chgrp`, `chmod`, etc. when setting up your nginx account, but with `.*` as an argument? This can head up into `..` if used with the recursion flag `-r`

Comment: Definitely not me, though nginx has been running my server since the beginning. I know that they were recently moving the mysql database to a different part of the server - I'll look through the command logs later today. I assume there's nothing to worry about now, considering 'admin' was moved to 'nginx' group?

Comment: It's the _whole 'admin' directory belonged to group 'nginx'_ that would worry me.